# How to send Input form HTML From to SQLite3 database using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to create a guests registration form for guests arriving at the office.
I'm getting stuck sending the input from the form to a SQLite3 database.

If someone could help me that'll be awesome.

Thank you in advance

HTML:

```
{% block body %}

<form action="{{ url_for('my_form') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Gasten registratie</h1>
        <p>Vul dit formulier in om te registreren</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="First-Name"><b>Voornaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="First-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" name="Voornaam" required>

        <label for="Last-Name"><b>Achternaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Last-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw achternaam in" name="Achternaam" required>


        <label for="Company-name"><b>Bedrijfsnaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Company-name" placeholder="Vul hier uw bedrijfsnaam in" name="Bedrijfsnaam" required>


        <label for="Date"><b>Datum</b></label>
        <input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Selecteer de Datum" name="Datum" required />
        <hr>


        <p>In het kader van onze ISAE certificering registreren wij uw gegevens.</p>
        <p>Wij verwerken uw gegevens volgends de regels van het AVG.</p>
        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Registreren</button>
    </div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And my python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3 
from sqlite3 import Error

app = Flask(__name__) 

# Here I create a DB and a connection
def create_connection(db_file):
    connection = None;
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn 

# This is were I call the function for my db

create_connection("gast.db") 

# This is were I create the tables I want in the database 

def create_table(conn, guests):

    sql = """ INSERT INTO guests(voor_naam,achter_naam,bedrijfs_naam,datum)
              VALUES(?,?,?,?) """ 

    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql,guests)
    return cur.lastrowid


# here I insert the created tables
def main():
    database = r"gast.db"

    sql_create_guests_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guests (
                                        id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                        voor_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        achter_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        bedrijfs_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        datum date NOT NULL

                                    ); """

    conn = create_connection(database)

    if conn is not None:
        # maak gast table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_guests_table)

    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")



# index for the html page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


# sending input form form to db
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['POST'])
def my_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = conn.cursor()
        guest_vnaam = request.form.get('Voornaam')
        guest_anaam = request.form.get('Achternaam')
        guest_cnaam = request.form.get('Bedrijfsnaam')
        guest_datum = request.form.get('Datum')

        try:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO databasename.tablename (columnName,columnName,columnName,columnName Ci) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
            c.execute(sql,(guest_vnaam, guest_anaam, guest_cnaam,  guest_datum))
            connection.commit() 
            #or "conn.commit()" (one of the two)
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens'

# This is where I run the app 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The app runs, but when I click on the register button I get the following error:

File "/home/ronny/Desktop/registratieinc/app.py", line 70, in my_form
c = conn.cursor()
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined

Again any help or suggestions are very welcome (;

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used flask, however I know that in your code here

```
def create_connection(db_file):
    connection = None;
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn 

# This is were I call the function for my db

create_connection("gast.db")
```

you are returning your connection, however since you aren't handling the return, the variable `conn` stays local.

Try something like `conn = create_connection("gast.db")`

Here is an example of how you can open the connection when you need it.

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['POST'])
def my_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        conn = create_connection("gast.db") 

        c = conn.cursor()
        guest_vnaam = request.form.get('Voornaam')
        guest_anaam = request.form.get('Achternaam')
        guest_cnaam = request.form.get('Bedrijfsnaam')
        guest_datum = request.form.get('Datum')

        try:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO databasename.tablename (columnName,columnName,columnName,columnName Ci) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
            c.execute(sql,(guest_vnaam, guest_anaam, guest_cnaam,  guest_datum))
            conn.commit() 
            #or "conn.commit()" (one of the two)
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens'
        finally:
            conn.close()
```

Additionally, you'll want to add a `finally:` to your main function where you're creating the table and close your connection there as well.

Comment: But when I adjust that I get the following error....

File "/home/ronny/Desktop/registratieinc/app.py", line 70, in my_form
c = conn.cursor()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 139874622285632 and this is thread id 139874510690048.

Comment: That message tells us we should only be opening our sqlite connection when we need it and close it when we're done. I'll edit my post to show how you can achieve that.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now I don't get an error but now it still cant save the input data. It goes to the except part of the code. So I got to the screen 'er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens' ('something went wrong with saving your data' translated to english)